# What could be done to get the old values back in the table after execution of any update query on it?

Tags: php, mysql

What could be done to get the old values back in the table after execution of any update query on it ?

I am using PHP and Mysql DB

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default: **nothing**. There is no way.

Unless maybe:

- You were in a **transaction** (used
  BEGIN) and did not yet COMMIT. You
  can then ROLLBACK.
- You started the statement with setting **AUTOCOMMIT** to 0. See above.
- You have got a recent **backup of your row/table/schema/database**. For example, using *MySQLDump*.
- You have got a recent **backup of your filesystem** where your database resides. For example, *tape drives* or  a networker.
- You have a **logfile with statements** (eg the *mysql query log* or the *binary log*) enabled. Then you could start with an empty table and re-execute the commands that filled the table.
- The database is **mirrored** on another system and the mirror is not yet updated (be fast...)

But otherwise, nope, sorry. The information is lost.

You should start thinking about doing one of the things stated above (backups are a MUST!, logging is adviseable while developing if your server can handle it) to avoid these situations in the future.

Comment: Ugh - if you take the time to answer and add proper formatting, someone else will be faster and post an incomplete answer, but get all the points...

Comment: Korrect :) Certainly This the Law of Nature

Comment: You can start with posting the most important information you have, and then go back and improve your answer. This will actually help you getting higher scores... Plus, your answer will get accepted, and then voted up further, so it's not as bad as you think. Please keep posting **good** answers :)

Comment: In india We Believe The More U wait The More U get, See ur answer got Selected.... :)

Answer (score 4):

If you're using transactions and haven't committed the transaction, you just do a rollback.

If you aren't using a transactions or have committed your transaction then you're reliant on one of:

- backups
- application-specific functionality eg a trigger on the table to log updates that will allow you to reconstruct the old values.

There is no other native mechanism.